# Trying to mount an mdadm array.

Tags: raid, mdadm

I am trying to power up an older Linux box of mine to pull some data off. For the life of me, I can't remember why I had it set up this way.
The intent was for the home directory to be a raid 1 array. I am just trying to get it mounted now.
When I try to mount it, using

```
sudo mount /dev/md4 /home2
```

And I get the error:

```
mount: you must specify the filesystem type
```

Of course, I now try:

```
sudo mount -t ext4 /dev/md4 /home2
```

And I get:

```
mount: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/md4,
   missing codepage or helper program, or other error
   In some cases useful info is found in syslog - try
   dmesg | tail  or so

[ 2677.835918] FAT-fs (md4): invalid media value (0x00)
[ 2677.835920] FAT-fs (md4): Can't find a valid FAT filesystem
[ 2853.426006] EXT4-fs (md4): VFS: Can't find ext4 filesystem
```

I know that something is definitely screwed up. Can anyone help me get this sorted out...please? Let me know what to post and I can get it added here. Thanks. Really.

Comment: Did you fiirst [assemble and run the array?](http://serverfault.com/a/383373/336187)

Comment: The output of `sudo file -sL /dev/md4` might be helpful